# How to make a new parent class for an element w/ jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have something like

```
<div>
  <!-- other stuff then-->
  <button>Hey</button>
</div>
```

and I'd like to make that (using Javascript/JQuery)

```
<div>
  <!-- other stuff then-->
  <div class="bw">
    <button>Hey</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is that possible? I couldn't find anything with material on it online…but, I'm a totally JS noob, so I'm probably not using the right terminology. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) for this:

```
$("button").wrap("<div class='bw'></div>");
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/jE2rK/), for wrapping multiple elements, use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), here's [a full list of the wrapping functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/).